# Getting lot of space in a table lay out for row (r=0) from data table in window form c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

Getting lot of space between labels in a Table Layout for row (r=0) from data table but when it comes to r=1 their are no spaces between lables.Here is my code:

```
                   for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                   {
                     Label line = new Label();
                     Label Quest = new Label();
                     Label Quest = new Label();
                     Quest.Text = Convert.ToInt32(r + 1).ToString();
                     Quest.Text = dt.Rows[r]["Ques"].ToString();
                     Quest.AutoSize = true;
                     tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Quest);
                     tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Quest);
                    }
```

Comment: Please don't join together for loops.. but having saying that I don't think you need the `r` variable anyway since it will always seem to have the same value as `i` -Also, your question is unclear, what do you mean a lot of space?

Comment: thanks for your reply . i had made changes. i am getting gap between labels for i=0; but when i =1; etc.. their is no gap between the labels. (Gap means getting space between the labels)@Sayse

Comment: Can you attach an image showing your problem? (if you cant edit it in yourself you can include a *direct link* to the image then someone can edit it into your question)